# SDL 2012 UI, error on initializing,

Tags: javascript, user-interface, tridion

I have completed setup for `SDL 2012 UI` , however when i am trying to access the website UI ribbon bar does not appear on page. It seems it is not able to initialize UI and throw following Javascript error.

> Unable to get unique id for element.

`Bootstrap.aspx?mode=js`, line 4 character 3749

Any pointers will be great.

Answer (score 2):

You may have an access issue to the bootstrap.js.  Use firebug to see if you get a 403 on this asset.  If so go into the CM's IIS console and ensure that this SiteEdit site accessible.

Comment: Upon rereading your question I think Boris may be right in that some other script on your page is interfering with the bootstrap.  Also, what browser and version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The difference of SDL 2012 UI from previous versions is you'll not see website UI ribbon, but SDL UI Button. By click on this button you'll be redirected to new page with SDL UI interface controls and your content page.

Looks like Bootstrap.js script is loaded on the content page but there is an error happens on the time script generates SDL UI Button or after you click on it (it's not fully clear from your question).

That could be because website scripts do manipulation with page's content. Ineeded browser debug tools will give more details.